# Simple SharePoint Validation - What is wrong with my formula?

Tags: validation, sharepoint, formula

I know the answer to this question will be simple, which is why I feel silly for asking but if someone could advise what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate it.

I have a list library that stores documents. It is mandatory that each of these documents has a date logged in the *Next Contract Review Date* column unless the document is marked as *Expired* or *Terminated* in the *Has the Contract Expired / Terminated* column, which is a choice drop-down column.

The following is the formula I'm using:

```
     =IF([Has the Contract Expired / Terminated]="",
     IF([Next Contract Review Date])<>"",TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

When I enter this formula into the Validation Settings for the library, I am advised that there is an error with my formula upon pressing the Save button.

To confirm, the column named *Next Contract Review Date* is set to be mandatory within the actual column settings.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it to work:

```
 =IF(OR([Has the Contract Expired / Terminated] = "Terminated", [Has the 
 Contract Expired / Terminated] = "Expired"),ISBLANK([Next Contract Review 
 Date]),NOT(ISBLANK([Next Contract Review Date])))
```

Answer (score 0):

A minor change in your formula as shown below related to brackets removal after review date.
=IF([Has the Contract Expired / Terminated]="",
     IF([Next Contract Review Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)

I tested with demo data similar requirement and it worked fine.Here is the formula used:
=IF(OR(Choice1="BB",Choice1="CC"),TRUE,IF(DateOfBirth<>"",TRUE,FALSE))

For your requirement, try the following formula also
=IF(OR([Has the Contract Expired / Terminated]="Expired",([Has the Contract Expired / Terminated]="Terminated"),TRUE,IF([Next Contract Review Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE))

Comment: Hello Thangu. Many thanks for your response and suggestion. However, I am still encountering a problem. The column named _Next Contract Review Date_ is mandatory (as defined in the column settings) so this validation appears to be overriding all other validation I'm trying to apply. In other words, if _Next Contract Review Date_ must be blank as the _Has the Contract / Expired_ is marked at _Terminated_ or _Expired_ then I still get an error advising that the date cannot be left blank.

Comment: I have since switched off the mandatory requirement of the column but that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above steps, please ensure that the column is Not Required column.
List Settings->Select your column Next Contract Review Date

Select No under 
Require that this column contains information:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG4jw.png)

Comment: Hello Thangu. I have already made the column non-mandatory although after making this change, nothing happens when pressing the Save button. I feel there may be a minor error in the code.

Comment: Hello Artical, Could you please check that both the columns [Has the Contract Expired / Terminated] and [Next Contract Review Date] are not mandatory.

Comment: Hello Thangu. For some reason, I was having some trouble with the blank entry on the choice drop-down so I changed the options to N/A (default), Expired and Terminated. I then reworked your first suggestion to read:

         =IF([Has the Contract Expired / Terminated]="N/A", IF([Next Contract 
         Review Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)

Neither column is mandatory. Saving properties where N/A is selected forces a date to be selected (correct) but saving properties where is Expired or Terminated is selected (with or without a date) throws an error (incorrect).

Comment: Hello Article, I think you are almost there to the right answer with a minor change. Could you please try with the following formula where False at last is changed from False to True.=IF([Has the Contract Expired / Terminated]="N/A", IF([Next Contract Review Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE). In case you face issues with the above formula. Use this: =IF(OR([Has the Contract Expired / Terminated]="Expired",([Has the Contract Expired / Terminated]="Terminated"),TRUE,IF([Next Contract Review Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE))

Comment: Hello Thangu. The first formula still does not work when selecting Expired or Terminated, it doesn't matter if there is a date or not. However, having N/A selected does force the user to have a date so it half works. As for the second formula, I get the error message 'The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported" when trying to save it. Any other ideas please? :-(

Comment: No other ideas? If not, I'll have to try elsewhere.